# When I assign prototype to function I get undesired output

Tags: javascript

Please follow the code below,

```
var fn79 = function(){

    var Student = function(_name){
        this.name = _name;
    };


    Student.prototype = function(){
        print("Inside Prototype function");
    };


    //Student.prototype = {}

    var obj1 = new Student("Ricky");

    Student.prototype.lastName = "Gonzales";

    var obj2 = new Student("Jacky");

    print(obj1.name+" - "+obj1.lastName);
    print(obj2.name+" - "+obj2.lastName);   
};

fn79();
```

The output I get is

```
D:\Rahul Shivsharan\MyPractise\JavaScriptCommandLine>java -jar js-14.jar prac.js
- Gonzales
- Gonzales

D:\Rahul Shivsharan\MyPractise\JavaScriptCommandLine>
```

From above output you can see I am not able to print "name" property of objects.

now if I change the the code to as below,

```
    var fn79 = function(){

    var Student = function(_name){
        this.name = _name;
    };

    /*
    Student.prototype = function(){
        print("Inside Prototype function");
    };
    */

    Student.prototype = {}

    var obj1 = new Student("Ricky");

    Student.prototype.lastName = "Gonzales";

    var obj2 = new Student("Jacky");

    print(obj1.name+" - "+obj1.lastName);
    print(obj2.name+" - "+obj2.lastName);   
};

fn79();
```

I get the desired output as

```
D:\Rahul Shivsharan\MyPractise\JavaScriptCommandLine>java -jar js-14.jar prac.js
Ricky - Gonzales
Jacky - Gonzales

D:\Rahul Shivsharan\MyPractise\JavaScriptCommandLine>
```

Why my First example was not working properly.

Function is an object itself in javascript.

What I thought is,

```
Student.prototype = function(){
       print("Inside Prototype function");
}
```

Student's prototype is pointing to function which itself is an object.

So why "name" is not getting printed in my first case, and how prototype assigning to function effects it.

Comment: A prototype is **not** a function, its an object which can contain functions! Use `Student.prototype = { print: function(){ print('Inside!'); }}` or something.

Comment: but, function is also an object, right ?

Comment: Not in the same sense. Yes, in JS a function 'is' an object, but it cannot be a prototype be itself. I'll post something, gimme a mo.

Comment: @somethinghere: Of course it can be a prototype - every object can. The OP demonstrated using it as such successfully.

Comment: @Bergi Yes it can, but it certainly won't do anyone any good.

Comment: @somethinghere: That indeed. It confuses most people to hell :-) Especially when they try to use `.name` properties.

Comment: @Bergi yeah thats why I didn't really want to confuse matters by focusing on the assignment of the function (the question clearly isn't from someone with a huge lot of experience in JS). But hey, I did learn something from your post about the `name` thingy (I rarely have to use it though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with functions is that they do have a non-writable [`.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) property. This non-writability even affects the objects that inherit from the function, in your case the `Student` instances, so the assignment fails:

```
var Student = function(name){
    console.log(this.name);
    this.name = name;
    console.log(this.name);
};
Student.prototype = function ProtoName() {};
console.log(Student.prototype.name);
new Student("test");
```

You'll just see the string `"ProtoName"` thrice.

You can use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to make it more obvious that the `.name =` fails:

```
var Student = function(name){
    "use strict";
    this.name = name;
};
Student.prototype = function ProtoName() {};
new Student("test");
```

You'll get an `Error: Invalid assignment in strict mode`.

You can work around the non-writability by creating the `.name` property on the `Student` instance using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) instead of the simple assignment, but really you just should not use a function object as a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of what prototypes are and how you should use them. I will refactor your code and tell you why this works the way it works, as well as the general consensus for how to use them:

You declare a function - this is called the `Constructor` function. It will construct all the variables etc..

```
function Student(firstname, lastname){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
```

Your prototype is an object with `keys` and `values`. This is simply because your prototype will not exist on actual products, it will act as if it's right there *on* the element (and not in element.prototype). We'll get to that, but for now you should keep in mind that *variables* are best declared inside your constructor function above, and *methods* are best in the prototype. You can mix them, but it's an easy divide and it keeps your code clear.

```
Student.prototype = {
    showName: function(){ return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname; }
};
```

Now when we construct an instance of student, we can use the method `showName` as such:

```
var gonzales = new Student('Johny','Gonzales');
console.log(gonzales.showName()); // 'Johny Gonzales'
```

Also note that we do not mention the prototype on a consturcted object. It is still 'available' in `__proto__` as it's inherited etc... But from a normal point of view this does not matter.

Variables are also directly accessible, using by simple using dot notation. By the way, keep in mind that variables and methods share the same namespace!

```
console.log(gonzales.firstname); // Johny
```

You cannot set the prototype as a function itself (unless it is a self executing function that returns an object). `Functions` in javascript, although considered objects, are different beasts with their own magic - do not treat them like objects as they will not treat it kindly. Don't try to do this, as it can break some Javascript inheritance and will create countless bugs you cannot squash.

For more details and accurate naming, see this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_objects

Answer (score -1):

While it is true that an function in JS in the end is also an Object, it's not the same way the other way around, since that would mean every Object is also a function.

The prototype Object holds all the functions the prototype has. This is VERY important for Object inheritance and the like.

If you think back to memory schema's it's like this:

```
{
    hi : function hi(){}, // pointer to the function 'hi'
    bye : function bye(){}, // pointer to function 'bye'
    data : { planet : 'earth' } // pointer to an Object with a pointer to a String which contains 'earth'
}
```

If you overwrite the Object with a function, it all dies.
Mainly since JS 'knows' that a the an Objects prototype is supposed to hold functions or other objects, and does not 'execute' the prototype Object itself.

So basically, it's more like an index used by JS to find stuff that you may or may not need in an Class' instance

Answer (score -1):

When you set the prototype of the `Student` object like this :

```
Student.prototype = function(){
     print("Inside Prototype function");
};
```

The prototype of `Student` will be this simple function as [@somethinghere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991619/somethinghere) pointed out, (instead of containing the function `constructor` and the object `__proto__`), so all the properties and the functions of `Student` will be removed. This is why the property `name` will be removed.

And when you add the second property `lastname` to `Student`:

```
Student.prototype.lastName = "Gonzales";
```

The prototype of `Student` will now has the property `lastname`.

And as [@somethinghere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991619/somethinghere) pointed out :

> every instance of Student will now share that last name

[More informations about the prototype of an Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: Might be good to mention that _every_ instance of Student will now share that last name, though. I am wondering though, that function declaration will not be the only function _in_ the prototype, but will _be_ the prototype, so this has got to screw up JS's built-in systems.

Comment: @somethinghere - You're absolutely right, I'll update my post. Thank you for your feeback.